# CMA Problems (Mistakes on Design)

Tags: linux, debugging, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

> CMA Problems

1.Reserve contiguous memory space and let contiguous memory allocation to be primary client of the area.

2.Share the reserved area with secondary clients.

3.Reclaim memory used by secondary clients whenevera primary client requests.

Above mention problems creates issue of latency and allocation failed.
Is there any solution for above problems.

Comment: You added several tags that don't seem to be related to your question. What is the problem you want to solve? For debugging memory leaks you may use `valgrind`.

Comment: @Bodo see the question again, and let me know if anything you have.

Comment: You should tell more details about your program, programming language and development environment. Why do you think it's memory fragmentation? Maybe you do not free all memory you allocated. searching for keywords "valgrind" and "android" brought me to AddressSanitizer, see https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/asan.html

Comment: @Bodo , see updated question.

Answer (score 1):

`strace` is used to know the different system calls and signals that your program is making while it is running. Your program need not be debug built.

Example:

`strace ls`

This will give all the system calls that the `ls` commands make while it is executing.

The ptrace system call provides a means by which a parent process may observe and control the execution of another process, and examine and change its core image and registers. It is primarily used to implement breakpoint debugging and system call tracing.

Comment: What about ptrace ? Can you please elaborate above statement, already read man pages.

Comment: This is not the correct way - You have changed the question completely. If you want to ask a new question, please post a NEW question- do not update the old question